# How can I pass two different types of Maps to a method?

Tags: java, methods, dictionary

I have two maps like this:

```
Map<Long, MyObject> myMap1 = new HashMap<Long, MyObject>()

Map<Integer, Set<Long>> myMap2 = new HashMap<Long, Set<Long>>()
```

How can I pass a map of only those two types of maps to a method without passing a generic `Object` or overloading the method?

```
public void method() {
    //method for maps
}
```

Comment: Should the second one be  `HashMap<Integer, Set<Long>>`?

Comment: Wow you guys are harsh.  What is the point in putting the method?  The method is not the question, but how I pass my maps as a parameter.  There is absolutely no reason for down voting for leaving out the method.

Comment: `public void method(Map<Long, MyObject> map1) {...}`...?

Comment: My question is how can I control what types of maps are passed to the method without overloading the method?

Comment: @code4me Then say so in the question. We had no idea what exactly you were asking.

Comment: My ESP is telling me what you're really asking is how you deal with that since type erasure won't let you create two methods with the same name and signature?

Comment: @BrianRoach I guess there is no way to do an `or` in a method signature?

Comment: If the second type in your `Map`s had some commonality you could do `Map<Long, ? extends BaseClass>` but since they don't ... you're basically out of luck beyond `? extends Object`. Without more context as to *why* you'd want to do what you're trying to do, I don't have many suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use what different types have in common if you want to use them in the same method.

For

```
Map<Long, MyObject> myMap1 = new HashMap<Long, MyObject>();
Map<Integer, Set<Long>> myMap2 = new HashMap<Integer, Set<Long>>();
```

the maximum they have in common is:

```
void method(Map<? extends Number, ? extends Object> map) {
    Number key = ?? (you know it is a Number but that's not helping much)
    Object object = map.get(key);
    object.IDonTKnowWhatTypeYouAre();
}
```

That's probably not useful because you basically know nothing about the type you can use within the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void method1(Map<Long, MyObject> map) {
    //method for map
}

public void method2(Map<Integer, Set<Long>> map) {
    //method for map
}
```

And you can call it with `method1(myMap1)` and `method2(myMap2)`.

Comment: In my question I'm asking how I can pass a map (singular) to the method that only accepts maps of the two types I provided?

Comment: Are you saying to pass a null value?

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but I edited the answer for what I understand from you now.

Answer (score -1):

You could declare the method for the erasure type `Map` without generic parameters, or for `Map<?, ?>`, but would lose the type safety of the generic parameters. Hence the compiler will give you some warnings.

Thus, you should normally avoid this.